# BASS.DLL | Радио | Название песни

Tags: delphi, bass.dll

Не удается получить название песни у второго потока.

Получаю так:

```pascal
function Meta(URL: String): String;
var
  Media: Cardinal;
begin
  BASS_Init(-1, 44100, BASS_UNICODE, 0, nil);
  Media := BASS_StreamCreateURL(PChar(URL), 0, BASS_UNICODE, nil, nil);
  Result := String(AnsiString(BASS_ChannelGetTags(Media, BASS_TAG_META)));
  BASS_Free;
end;
```

Результаты трех потоков

**Поток #1**: https://graalradio.com:8124/space
**Результат**: StreamTitle=''Zanio - Will (Elevate Raggapop Inc Remix)'';

**Поток #2**: http://air.radiorecord.ru:805/rus_320
**Результат**:

**Поток #3**: http://wargaming.fm/1
**Результат**: StreamTitle=''Promise Land & GLDN - Blow Ya Mind (Radio Edit)'';

К примеру **MPC-HC** отображает нормально

[image]

Пробовал получать другие теги, но результаты были пустыми.

Как быть?

---

**UPD**

Проверил потоки по совету в ответе от **t3f**

**x32**

[image]

**x64**

[image]

Забьем пока на **x64** и проверим другие потоки.

[image]

В общем всё печально, легче брать эти данные напрямую из потоков.
Но как это сделать?

Comment: Может он тупо в кириллицу не умеет? `AnsiString` как бы намекает, если тег в UTF8 какой-нибудь (или что там допустимо), то он может обломаться на чтении тега вообще. Более новой версии, с юникодом, нет?

Comment: @Alekcvp Я многие иностранные потоки пробовал, из почти всех потоков результат был пустым.

Comment: Найдите в интернете несколько файлов, теги в которых читаются и НЕ читаются BASS'ом и посмотрите на версии тегов и кодировку полей. Ну и на код ошибки, да.

Answer (score 0):

> Как быть?

Для начала - проверять возвращаемые значения и коды ошибок, чтобы точно знать что происходит. Например так:

```
function Meta(URL: String): String;
var Media: Cardinal; TagPtr: PAnsiChar;
begin
  if not BASS_Init(-1, 44100, BASS_UNICODE, 0, nil) then
    ShowMessage('Init failed with code: ' + IntToStr(BASS_ErrorGetCode));
  Media := BASS_StreamCreateURL(PAnsiChar(URL), 0, BASS_UNICODE, nil, nil);
  if Media = 0 then
    ShowMessage('StreamCreateURL failed with code: ' + IntToStr(BASS_ErrorGetCode));
  TagPtr := BASS_ChannelGetTags(Media, BASS_TAG_META);
  if TagPtr = nil then
    ShowMessage('ChannelGetTags failed with code: ' + IntToStr(BASS_ErrorGetCode));
  BASS_Free;
  Result := TagPtr;
end;
```

И только потом, когда будет точно известно где и какая ошибка происходит, уже можно будет судить о причинах.